# How do I get this function to return a new array for every item past the first one and the string "No items found in cart"?

Tags: javascript

So, I am new to JavaScript and I am having trouble with making a function work the way I want it to. As it stands, it prints the contents of "tomato" just fine and can tell if an item is not with in the list ... sort of. If I enter "t-shirt" or "soap", it does not add its contents into the newArray variable and adds "Item not found" instead. So, it does not recognize anything past "tomato". Another issue is that it does not tell me if an array is not empty, so it never shows "No items found in cart", just an empty array. Here is what I have tried so far. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
let items =  
    [
      {
        name: "tomato",
        type: "produce",
        price: 0.99
      }, 
      
      {
        name: "soap",
        type: "cleaning",
        price: 0.99
      },
      
      {
        name: "t-shirt",
        type: "clothing",
        price: 5.99
      }
    ]
    
    function searchItem(items,string)
    {
      let newArray = []; 
      for (i=0;i<items.length;i++)
      { 
          if (string === items[i].name)
          {
            newArray.push(items[i])
            break
          }
            else if(string != items[i].name)
            {
              newArray.push("Item not found")
              break
            }
             else
            {
              return "Item does not exist"
            }
      }
      return newArray
    }
    
    searchItem(items,"tomato")
```

Comment: Its because "break" when item not found and returning "No items found in cart" within "for loop" .  You have to run complete for loop then determine if did found or not. May be set some local variable in loop as `let found = false;` then set to `found = true` when it match. Then outside for loop check this found var and return result.

Comment: what is the difference between `Item not found`, `Item does not exist`, and `No items found in cart` ?

Comment: @IhsanFajarRamadhan "Item not found" means item does not exist in the given array. "No items found in cart" in cart means there is an empty array given. As for "Item does not exist", it means the same thing as "Item not found" and I accidently left in in as I was testing out scope. I will edit that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the logic, you tried to evaluate your search result in the loop. that's why as @cjmling suggested, if your search value does not match the first index, it will always result in `item not found`. So the soulution based on your description is like this:

```js
const items = [
  { name: "tomato", type: "produce", price: 0.99 },
  { name: "soap", type: "cleaning", price: 0.99 },
  { name: "t-shirt", type: "clothing", price: 5.99 }
]

function searchItem(items, string) {
  let newArray = [];
  // if the cart is empty return this
  if (items.length === 0) {
    return "No items found in cart"
  }
  // if the cart is not empty run the loop
  for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (string === items[i].name) {
      newArray.push(items[i])
    }
  }
  // if search result is 0, then return this
  if (newArray.length === 0) {
    return ["Item not found"]
  } else {
    return newArray
  }
}

console.log(searchItem(items, "tomato"));
console.log(searchItem(items, "soap"));
console.log(searchItem([], "tomato"));
console.log(searchItem(items, "human"));
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the issue with the logic handled in `searchItem` function.

You should set `"Item not found"` only after the loop execution is completed, or else if the first item in the array doesnot matches with the search element, it will return `"Item not found"` without checking the items below it.

In your code you are looping through the `items` array and checking the `name` of each item in the `items` array. If the name is matching with the paremater of the function, you are pushing that to the output array and breaking the function. If you are looking to find only the first element with that value, adding a break is fine there. If you want to find all the combinations with that string, you can avoid the break at that line (I went for this approach).

The issue comes in the `else if` part. If the `name` of item from this array doesnot matches with the string, it will push `"Item not found"` to the `newArray` and breaks the loop. So this will break for the first non matching element in the array and stops execution of the further loop. So if the searching element is not at the first index, the function will stop execution and push `"Item not found"` to the `"newArray"` and breakes. Rest of the code blocks will never execute.

To make your function working, move the `else-if`, `else` out of the loop. Let the loop completes the execution, after that check the length of `newArray`. If the length is 0, seach item is not found, or else item is found.

**EDIT:** Also you have to inegrated `"No items found in cart"` logic. For this you have to check the length of cart input. If its zero you have to return `"No items found in cart"`

**Your working solution**

```js
const items = [
  { name: "tomato", type: "produce", price: 0.99 },
  { name: "soap", type: "cleaning", price: 0.99 },
  { name: "t-shirt", type: "clothing", price: 5.99 }
]

function searchItem(cart, string) {
  if (cart.length === 0) {
    return "No items found in cart";
  }
  let newArray = [];
  for (i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
    if (string === cart[i].name) {
      newArray.push(cart[i])
      break
    }
  }
  return newArray.length === 0 ? "Item not found" : newArray;
}

const emptyCart = [];
const output = searchItem(items, "tomato");
const output1 = searchItem(items, "soap");
const output2 = searchItem(items, "t-shirt");
const output3 = searchItem(items, "t-shirts");
const emptySearch = searchItem(emptyCart, "tomato");
console.log(output);
console.log(output1);
console.log(output2);
console.log(output3);
console.log(emptySearch);
```

This can be easily achieved using `Array.filter` (To find multiple occurance of the string) or `Array.find` (to find single occurance of the string) without using a for loop as below.

```js
const items = [
    { name: "tomato", type: "produce", price: 0.99 },
    { name: "soap", type: "cleaning", price: 0.99 },
    { name: "t-shirt", type: "clothing", price: 5.99 }
  ]

function searchItem(cart, string) {
  if (cart.length === 0) {
    return "No items found in cart";
  }
  let newArray = cart.filter((item) => item.name === string);
  return newArray.length === 0 ? "Item not found" : newArray;
}

const emptyCart = [];
const output = searchItem(items, "tomato");
const output1 = searchItem(items, "soap");
const output2 = searchItem(items, "t-shirt");
const output3 = searchItem(items, "t-shirts");
const emptySearch = searchItem(emptyCart, "tomato");
console.log(output);
console.log(output1);
console.log(output2);
console.log(output3);
console.log(emptySearch);
```